# Connect ACF radio field with taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

My site has a Custom Post Type called **Experts** and a taxonomy called **Languages**. I want if you select a term from **Languages** taxonomy (assuming "Arabic" is selected) you can select options from another radio metabox related to that term, those options are Native, Fluent and Basic any of these 3. So, there will be an option to select Native / Fluent / Basic separately for each language, from which it will be understood what language the expert knows and what is his/her skill in which language. With ACF Pro, that radio metabox can be easily made, now the challenge is, how to connect it with each term of **Languages** taxonomy? Thank you.

Tried ACF location rules to see if there was an option to bind the radio metabox separately for each Language taxonomy term. But found nothing.

The purpose is to take the value to filter the experts using **Search and Filter Pro** plugin, but that's in the later part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.